# parser csv fie with php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file

```
ID  PARENT  NAME
1   NULL    Consumer Electronics
2   NULL    Mobile Accessories
3   NULL    Gaming
4   3       xbox
5   3       playstation
6   2       iPad & iPhone
7   1       Usb cables
8   1       Battery
```

and I want this result, with a php script

```
ID  NAME
4   Gaming | xbox
5   Gaming | playstation
6   Mobile Accessories | iPad & iPhone
7   Consumer Electronics | Usb cables
8   Consumer Electronics | Battery
```

How can I do? Thanks

Comment: I tried to excel, but I have no idea how I can do it in php

Comment: You need http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 0):

Try reading a line.
Then look at the

```
 explode();
```

function.

Then check if you have nulls, and do whatever is necessary. Logic should be simple.

Also try using php docs, They are quite comprehensive.

Not sure if you're doing this for uni, but you should try even if you fail, it's the best way to learn ;)

Good luck :)